# How to disable Complete Button for each list Created?

Tags: javascript

I am touching up my to do up. I managed to get the complete button disabbled when the user clicks the edit button, but it only does it for the first list, which is weird,because, if I complete any of the list it completes no matter where it is in the index, but the complete button only disables on index 0.

Function that renders the list:

```
function renderList() {
  // This resets the list innerHTML to the new list
  el.list.innerHTML = taskList.map(function (data, i) {
    return `<div class="task">
            <div class="task-content">
                <div class="task-set" data-id="${data.id}">
                <input class="new-task-created" value="${
                  data.taskNew
                }" readonly style="${data.textDecoration ? "text-decoration: line-through" : ""}"></input>
                <input class="due-date" type="date" value="${
                  data.taskDate
                }" readonly></input>
                <input class="due-time" type="time" value="${
                  data.taskTime
                }" readonly></input>
            </div>
    
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <button onclick="editItem(event, ${i})" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
                <button onclick="deleteItem(event, ${i})" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
                <button onclick="completeItem(event, ${i})" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
        </div>`
  });

el.input.value = "";
}
```

Edit button function

```
//function that that edits tasks with date and time.
function editItem(event, i) {


  const editEl = event.target.closest(".task");
  let taskUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".new-task-created");
  let dateUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-date");
  let timeUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-time");
  let editbtn = editEl.querySelector(".edit");
 
  **let selectComplete = document.querySelector(".complete")**
  
  if (editbtn.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "edit") {
    taskUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
    dateUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
    timeUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
    taskUpdate.focus();

    //Set the disable for the complete button.
    selectComplete.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    editbtn.innerHTML = "Save";
  } else {
    taskUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    dateUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    timeUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    **selectComplete.removeAttribute('disabled');**
    editbtn.innerHTML = "Edit";
    taskList[i] = {
      id: taskList[i].id,
      taskNew: taskUpdate.value,
      taskDate: dateUpdate.value,
      taskTime: timeUpdate.value,
    };
    // store the list on localstorage because data changed
    storeList();
    // render list again because you've added a new entry
    renderList();
  }
}
```

I indicated the the two points to look at with astrixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only disabled the first button because you are using `querySelector()` which can only grab 1 single element.

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to grab all elements that match the criteria, and from there loop through them if needed.

But honestly I think you can get your desired result with something like this instead.

```
let selectComplete = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".complete");
```

This instead takes whatever button was clicked, gets the parent (which should be the `action-buttons` element) and applies the querySelector to only that element, which in turn only grabs the complete button in the same `<div>` as the edit button.

Comment: Thank you for that, that looks about right, however, i am gertting this error: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined``` so the e, is not defined, is it becuase e is not in the paremeters of the ```function editItem(event, i)```

Comment: @LearningSmart Sorry, The `e` should actually be `event`. I updated my code snippet but basically you are taking the event object passed in (which in your case you called it `event`).

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. just so that I understand in what you did there, the event, is one of the parameters, which means anything passing through, the target, is targeting the parrentElement and the parrentElement  is getting the complete from the HTML  element using the querySelector? Am I correct in that understanding?

Comment: `event.target` takes the event object and gets the target or element that the event occurred on (for for a click, the target is whatever element was clicked). Then, we take that `event.target` and get the `parentElement` of that (which is `<div class="action-buttons">`). Now if you apply your `querySelector` to just that element, it will only grab the complete button closest to your edit button.